# How to compare values, ignoring diacritics, with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, diacritics, graphdb

I've been trying (with no success so far) to filter values with a "broader equals" condition. That is, ignoring diacritics.

```
select * where {  
  ?s per:surname1 ?t.
  bind (fn:starts-with(str(?t),'Maria') as ?noAccent1) .
  bind (fn:translate(str(?t),"áéíóú","aeiou") as ?noAccent2) .
} limit 100
```

To this moment, I've tried with [XPath](http://dbpedia.org/resource/XPath) functions `fn:contains`, `fn:compare`, `fn:translate`, `fn:starts-with`, but none of them seem to be working.

Is there any other way (other than chaining `replace`s) to add collation into these functions or achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath functions you mention are not part of the SPARQL standard really, so as you found out, you can't rely on them being supported out of the box (though some vendors may provide them as an add-on).

However, GraphDB (which is based on RDF4J) allows you to [create your own custom functions in SPARQL](http://docs.rdf4j.org/custom-sparql-functions/). It is a matter of writing a Java class that implements the `org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.algebra.evaluation.function.Function` interface, and registering it in the RDF4J engine by packaging it as a Java Service Provider Interface (SPI) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

SPARQL and REGEX do not support efficiently transliterating character maps. If you want an efficient implementation you would need a custom RDF4J custom as described by Jeen.

If you want a quick and dirty solution use this code sample:

```
PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX spif: <http://spinrdf.org/spif#>
select * where {
    BIND("Mariana" as ?t) .
    BIND("Márénísótú" as ?t2) .
    BIND (regex(str(?t),'^Maria') as ?noAccent1) .
    BIND (spif:replaceAll(
            spif:replaceAll(
                spif:replaceAll(
                    spif:replaceAll(
                        spif:replaceAll(str(?t2),"á","a"),
                        "é","e")
                    ,"í","i"),
                "ó","o"),
            "ú","u") as ?noAccent2) .
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can't rely on a replace chain, as it wont be just diacritics in the future. I was looking for a "cleaner" solution that implied a collated comparison